# XPages selected value work in XPiNC but not web browser

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm doing the quick XAgent style view export to excel. But first I need to get a the UNID of the documents that match the criteria that I selected on my XPage. I have a button that will get the number of document found. I've confirmed and verified that I have the documents based on the value that I select but it always return zero document in the alert when in web browser. For now the code in the button is as following:

```
uifrom = getComponent("from_dtpicker").getValue(); // a date-time picker
uito = getComponent("to_dtpicker").getValue(); // a date-time picker
uitag = getComponent("tag_combox").getValue(); // a combobox

var from:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime(uifrom);
from.setAnyTime();
var to:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime(uito);
to.setAnyTime();

var vw:NotesView = database.getView("(Document View by Tag)");
var docUNIDarray:Array = []; // for the quick XAgent excel export later on

if (uitag == "All") {
    var vec:NotesViewEntryCollection = vw.getAllEntries();
} else {
    var vec:NotesViewEntryCollection = vw.getAllEntriesByKey(uitag, true);
}

var total:Number = 0;

var ve:NotesViewEntry = vec.getFirstEntry();
while (ve != null) {
    // document must have StartDate and EndDate
    if (ve.getDocument().hasItem("StartDate") && ve.getDocument().hasItem("EndDate")) {
        var vefrom:NotesDateTime = ve.getDocument().getItemValue("StartDate").elementAt(0);
        vefrom.setAnyTime();
        // as long as the StartDate is between the selected from and to
        if (vefrom >= from && vefrom <= to) {
            if (ve.getDocument().getItemValueString("StaffName") != "Company") {
                docUNIDarray.push(ve.getDocument().getUniversalID());
                total += 1; 
            }
        }
    }
    ve = vec.getNextEntry(ve);
}

view.postScript('alert("total:'+total+', from:'+from+', to:'+to+', tag:'+uitag+'")');
```

Also, the only full refresh that I did is when clicking the button. There's also no scoped variable in this page. Only 2 date-time picker, a combobox, and the button itself. Any explanation for this? I'm confirmed the code is correct because it work in XPiNC.

The total number of documents that I got is supposed to be 18. If I append .toJavaDate() to from, to, and vefrom, then I get 10 documents which is wrong. I've checked the underlying value of "StartDate" and "EndDate" for each document and each value is of Time/Date like 08/12/2013 12:00:00 PM ZE8. I assume that converting and any date value in my code to NotesDateTime will ensure that all have the same type and can be compared to but for this one I'm totally don't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take out the time component in your comparison. There are several options to do that. First of all, go after the view entry and not the document and put all data into columns. For the date values use a string:

```
   @Text(@Year(startdate)*10000+@month(startdate)*100+@day(startdate))
```

Another approach would be dealing with the Java Date methods